# Invalid input: [, expected "+" or "-" neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran this query in neo4j:

```
MATCH (n1:`Anumber`)-[*..2]-(n2)
WHERE n1 <> n2
AND all(node in nodes(n1)-[*..2]-(n2) WHERE node:`Anumber` OR node:`Bnumber`)
WITH n1, n2, COLLECT(p) AS paths
WHERE size(paths) > 1
RETURN n1, n2, size(paths) AS degree, paths
```

but got this error:

```
Invalid input '[': expected "+" or "-" (line 3, column 27 (offset: 76))
"AND all(node in nodes(n1)-[*..2]-(n2) WHERE node:`Anumber` OR node:`Bnumber`)"
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use this logic:

```
MATCH p=(n1:Anumber)-[*..2]-(n2)
WHERE n1 <> n2 AND
  ALL(n IN NODES(p) WHERE n:Anumber OR n:Bnumber)
WITH n1, n2, COLLECT(p) AS paths
WHERE size(paths) > 1
RETURN n1, n2, size(paths) AS degree, paths
```

Comment: yes your code works well, thank you for your answer